# Which is the best secure way to bind a param in php

Tags: php, security, pdo, bind

which is the best secure way to bind a value ? I know that there are 3 ways

1.

```
$Email=$con->quote($Email);
$Example=$con->prepare("UPDATE Ex SET Email=:Email");
$Example->bindParam(':Email', $Email);
$Example->execute();
```

2.

```
$Email=$con->quote($Email);
$Example=$con->prepare("UPDATE Ex SET Email=:Email");
$Example->execute(array(
   ':Email' => $Email,
));
```

3.

```
$Email=$con->quote($Email);
$Example=$con->prepare("UPDATE Ex SET Email=:Email");
$Example->bindParam(':Email', $Email);
$Example->execute(array(
   ':Email' => $Email,
));
```

Comment: What do you mean by "secure way"? What insecurity are you trying to solve? Either one should be equally "secure". What you _should_ do is remove your call to `quote()`, since prepared statements don't need to be quoted. That would actually change the stored value.

Comment: You are doing the same thing.  Also you can bind using the question mark , ? Also

Comment: In any case, you're updating your entire database without a `WHERE` clause; I hope you realize that.

Comment: Third case is useless.

Comment: There's also a `bindValue` so more cases to come!

Comment: You don't have to quote your datas... the prepare method will do it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're all wrong. Since you're separately using `quote`, the final query will actually be equivalent to (assuming `$Email` is, say `foo@example.com`):

```
UPDATE Ex SET Email="\"foo@example.com\""
```

In other words, the quotes become part of the value, which is probably not what you want.

Either of these will do just fine:

```
$Example = $con->prepare('UPDATE Ex SET Email = :Email');
$Example->execute(array(':Email' => $Email));
```

```
$Example=$con->prepare('UPDATE Ex SET Email = :Email');
$Example->bindParam(':Email', $Email);
$Example->execute();
```

Doing *both* `bindParam` *and* passing an array to `execute` is nonsense, since the latter will simply override the former and `bindParam` will have been superfluous.

Comment: So if i use quotes, i should not use the bindparam or the execute (array(.. ?

Comment: @A.Rossi You _should not_ use quotes and you _should_ bind your parameters.

Comment: @A.Rossi `quote` is for when you concatenate a query by hand, e.g. `'UPDATE Ex SET Email = ' . $con->quote($Email)` - **which is something you should never ever be doing in this day and age**, always use parameterised queries instead, as shown above.

Comment: @deceze So if i quote, then i execute the array, such in the third example i could cause a security issue?Or i doing an useless staff, or i am increasing the security?

Comment: @A.Rossi As long as you're using a prepared statement and you're not concatenating your values into the query by hand (as shown in my previous comment), there is no security concern. However, `quote` is ***altering the data***, so you're putting different data into your database than you actually want.

Comment: @deceze recapping, the best optimized and secure way to avoid sql injection is just to use for example execute (array(... without use quotes and without bind params?        P.S:Thanks for your help!

Comment: @A.Rossi Use. Either. Of. The. Two. Code. Samples. In. My. Answer. No more, no less. `bindParam` allows for a third argument to specify the type of the bound value. Other than that, there's no difference between using it and `execute`.

Comment: @deceze so using quote, then use execute(array(....)); is useless for security?

Comment: @A.Rossi Yes...

Comment: @deceze thank your for everithing!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Those 3 methods are equal in terms of securing your code against for example SQL injection. No3 is redundant - you don't need to use `bindParam` and pass the params in `execute` (if there were different values for the params passed, one could overshadow the other but I didn't find anything about it in the docs)